# SoundPool application load time

Tags: android, audio, android-asynctask

I have used the SoundPool to load around 100 .mp3s into an application. This, however increases the load of the app from 3 seconds to 12 seconds.

I appreciate the SoundPool needs to load & decode the sounds into memory, but is this duration normal? Is there any way to load the sounds in the background without affecting the application load time ?

```
public void initSounds()
{
    soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Log.i("Initialising Sounds ------ > ",""+soundPool.toString() );


    Class raw = R.raw.class;
    Field[] fields = raw.getFields();

    Context con  = GlobalVars.ACTIVITY_1.getApplicationContext();

    for (int i = 1; i < 91; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            int id = fields[i].getInt(null);
            soundPoolMap.put(i, soundPool.load(con, id, 1));
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            Log.e("REFLECTION", String.format("%s threw IllegalAccessException.", fields[i].getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never used a soundPool with that many things in it. But I don't see any reason you couldn't do all of the loading in a background thread. Just besure to tell your main thread when you are done loading. And set it up so it knows not to try to play anything before the loading is complete.

Comment: There was no way around this. As a solution, I recommend loading the sounds when after the app has loaded. I did this as the user is entering log in details. It will hit a null pointer exception if a sound is called before it has loaded, but a small price to pay for a super fast start up.

Answer (score 0):

You are really lucky to get 12 seconds for 100 MP3 files, not event OGGs. My answer could no longer be so relevant right now as in 2020 I am struggling with a 50 second load time for 32 OGG files in soundpool.

Answer (score -1):

To make sound pool load faster you should use WAV